# sys.tables vs sp_tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got different row counts while performing following queries:

```
use MyDb

select * from sys.tables where name like  '%Abc%201502%'

exec sp_tables '%Abc%201502%'
```

I am not able to figure out why.

According to [this article](http://sqlhints.com/tag/sp_tables/) both of them must have been same!

Comment: sp_tables ? can I see that?

Comment: Do you have `views`? As per `ughai's` answer, if you have views, then the results may vary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **`sp_tables`**:
>    Is a stored procedure which returns a list of objects that can be queried in 
>       the current environment. This means any table or view, except synonym objects.
>
> **`sys.tables`**:
>   Is the system view which returns a row for each user table in SQL Server.

Comment: objects that can be queried in the current environment means with the access rights with current user ?

Comment: yes, whatever tables,views available for that user to query in any particular database.

Answer (score 1):

`sp_tables` returns list of objects which also includes views

As per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms186250.aspx)

> Returns a list of objects that can be queried in the current environment. This means any table or view, except synonym objects.

`sys.tables` returns list of tables only

As per  [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187406.aspx)

> Returns a row for each user table in SQL Server.

If you look at the column `TABLE_TYPE` from the result of `sp_tables`, you will see the type of object `TABLE/ VIEW`. Any view shown in `sp_tables` will not be shown in `sys.tables`.